# Throttling DropBox behind a firewall

Tags: firewalls, iptables

Our office network bandwidth gets choked when an employee copies a large file into her DropBox, since it gets downloaded on several machines (of other employees).

LAN Sync is an option, but needs to be configured on each machine. So is the bandwidth settings.

Is there a way I can control **via Firewall** settings (iptables and/or Squid)

- How much bandwidth is allowed (throttling) for DropBox sync
- Control Time-of-day when DropBox Sync is allowed (or bandwidth quota increased/decreased)

I guess I know how to write the firewall rules, but do not know which IP addresses/ports to target.

Kindly let me know if this is the wrong forum to ask this question.

Comment: So, your question boils down to "what are Dropbox ips and ports?"